# Get image in front when mouseover HTML

Tags: html, css

I have many images button in div and I want when I over mouse in an image it change the scr and show the same image but highlighted  with border.
Like here show before /after :

[image]

It work fine but when I have all other images together it show like that :

[image]

I think i need to set the image when the mouse over to be in front ;any idea?

Update :
code:

```
 <div id="mymap" width="720" style="width: 920px; height: 1227px; position: relative; left: 250px; transform: scale(.5,.5); -ms-transform: scale(.5,.5); -webkit-transform: scale(.5,.5); -o-transform: scale(.5,.5); -moz-transform: scale(.5,.5);">
        <img id="Burimi" style="position: absolute; left: 10px" src="Images/Reagion/Burimi-B.png" onmouseover="this.src='Images/reagion/Burimi-A.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Images/reagion/Burimi-B.png'" />
        <img id="N Batinah" style="position: absolute; left: 98px; top: 1px;" src="Images/Reagion/N Batinah-B.png" onmouseover="this.src='Images/reagion/N Batinah-A.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Images/reagion/N Batinah-B.png'" /></dive>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using simple CSS you should be able to change the `z-index` property. Assuming that the element is positioned either `absolute` or `relative`, just use

```
#mymap img:hover { z-index: 9999; }
```

Comment: fixed selector for css, please try it.

Comment: I tried as css inline -   <style type="text/css"> #mymap img:hover{
  
  z-index: 9999;
  
}
               </style>   NOt sure is that correct format?

Comment: <style>
#mymap img:hover { z-index: 9999; }
</style>

Answer (score 2):

```
#image:hover{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url('image2.png');
}
```

assuming #image is your image container , and `image2.png` is your hover-state image (while your are using background on container for all elements on the map, not just plain `img` tags).

It'll be quite dodgy though with detecting the hover on a correct elements.

Comment: am not sure if I understand ! see my code above. How to do that using css inline?

Comment: @user1476956 - you shouldn't use images for things like that. Use `DIV`s (or even better: `A` elements (links) with `display: block`) and put images as a background.

Comment: mmm am beginner , but then with div can i use it as button to go to my code behind?

Comment: @user1476956 - you won't need a javascript at all for this. Just google around for `css hover selector`

Comment: oky I read some. Now I have to put image as background , But i have here many images not one ! also i think i can use hover in an image why div ?

Comment: @user1476956 multiple divs - one for each image. Then position them with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

use the selector ":hover" to change your css when the mouse over